# InterSystems Cache: How to store macro name in a variable then evaluate it

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble, intersystems-iris

How can I store a macro name in a variable and then later use it?

For example:

```
Set myVariable = "AssertEquals"

Do $$$myVariable(...)
```

OR

```
Set myVariable = "$$$AssertEquals"

Do myVariable(...)
```

Thought I could do something like the following but that doesn't work either (I get CLASS DOES NOT EXIST).

```
Do $CLASSMETHOD("%UnitTest.TestCase","AssertEqualsViaMacro",....)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way, macroses expended during compile time, but you going to use them in runtime. I think you should better explain what you actually going to achieve. And you'll get more answers if you ask [here](https://community.intersystems.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks. Was just trying to loop though a set of UnitTests where the type of test (e.g. AssertEquals) is defined in a table column.

Comment: so, why not just use this way? `Do $CLASSMETHOD("current testcase class","AssertEqualsViaMacro",....)`

Comment: When I do the following I get an error. 
    Class UnitTests.MyTest Extends %UnitTest.TestCase
    {

    Method TestAdd()
    {
 
     ...
            ...
            ...
 
     Do $CLASSMETHOD("UnitTests.MyTest","AssertStatusOKViaMacro",tStatus, "Testing....")
See error below.
LogStateStatus:0:TestAdd:ERROR #5002: Cache error: <METHOD DOES NOT EXIST>zTestAdd+3^UnitTests.MyTest.1 *AssertStatusOKViaMacro,UnitTests.MyTest  <<==== **FAILED**

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$method($this, "AssertEqualsViaMacro", "here some description", ...args)`